# HTML : H1 class not centering

Tags: html, css

I am new with HTML and I am trying to center the H1 using css class but it is not working. I

My HTML is the following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"> 

</head>  
<body>
  <div class='title'>
    <h1>Technologies</h1>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS is the following :

```
multi-input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}  
button {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;  
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px 20px 0;
}   
body > div {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}   
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}    
div.title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I inspired myself from this tutorial : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP
I also tried adding this `h1 {text-align: center;}` in my css so that all H1s would be centered but it is still not working.
Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Your code works, are you sure your stylesheet is correctly connected?

Comment: Yes my css is in the same folder and I put the link to my css in link in the head

Comment: you did not give a width to the .title div, so there is no place to center the h1 in

Comment: If the link of my css is just /style.css because it is in the same folder it is fine ?

Comment: @RamondeVries that is incorrect, h1 is default a block element which takes 100% width. You don't need to specify any width to make this work.

Comment: yes the link is correct, but you can use f12 to inspect elements, and i assume you will see there that your div has no width. or maximum the with of the text inside the h1

Comment: @RamondeVries I tried with a width of 100% in the div but still not working

Comment: @ArnoTenkink the h1 gets a width with yes, but the div doesnt

Comment: @RamondeVries div is also a block level element and also get's 100% width as default.

Comment: But in the tutorial that I am following ( link in my question ) they do not mention width

Comment: @RamondeVries a div is also a block element.. that also spans the whole width, please learn more about block-level elements.

Comment: @cloned what did you change in my code to make it work with the snippet ?

Comment: @lolaa i didn't change anything, I just copy pasted your code. You need to debug this on your local system, open dev tools and check where exactly the browser fetches the `style.css` from. Check that the file is in this specific folder and can be reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delete the Slash (/) from `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">`

like this : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!--not this but u can delete u slice and u css will work again-->
<link type="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
<!--NOT .div title but u can try this in u html-->
<div class="title">
<h1>This Title</h1>
  <style>
    .title h1{
      text-align:center;
    }
  </style>
</div>


<!--THANKS,greetings from Indonesia-->
```

Comment: Instead of commenting inside the code, write text outside.

Answer (score -2):

Try this if you want to center your h1:

```
<style>
h1 {text-align: center;}
</style>
```